# Windows form colors

Tags: c#, winforms

i created windows form application usig Visual Studio 2010 in windows xp,problem is,moving to other versions like W7..or changing theme to upgraded versions in my sys also  changes the colors of form,so could any one tell me how to change form colors dynamically according to the OS or themes irrespective of those elements???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to comment the below code from the `Program.cs` file:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

And then apply the color or theme whatever you want and it will be affected irrespective of the Operating System.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use system theme, add this code on you Application startup:

```
Application.VisualStyleState =
    System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleState.NoneEnabled;
```